# drawing a chart in node red dashboard using csv file

Tags: csv, charts, dashboard, node-red

I'm trying to display a line chart in the dashboard from a csv file, this chart shows the change of the compressor's power(y-axis) with time(x-axis), i saw some videos showing that i must convert the time to unix format before passing it to the chart, and i did this and saw the output from the debug node and it shows that the date is converted but the chart in the dashboard doesn't seem to work nonetheless, here are the photos for the flow and chart

[image: flow]

[image: output from the debug node(labels is included but not shown in photo)]

[image: function code]

[image: Dashboard]